# Z-fighting along non-intersecting triangle edges

Tags: opengl, opentk, depth-buffer

I have an OpenGL program that is demonstrating unusual z-fighting and am lost to the cause of this.  It seems most of the fighting startx along the edges of triangles.

The two objects in the simplified test case do not intersect, as shown below.  I have ensured that the z-near and z-far values are reasonable (1 and 100, respectively).  The two objects are both within about 2 units of the origin, with the camera about 10 units away in the images shown.

No changes to OpenGL's default depth settings have been made, except that depth testing has been enabled.

The vertex and fragment shaders have been made as simple as they can be.

This is using OpenTK.  I have tried explicitly creating the window with a 32-bit depth buffer, but this also had no effect.

I have been over all four things the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm) lists as requirements for depth buffering.

Turning off depth testing eliminates the fighting, leaving objects overlapping in drawing order.  There is no culling or stenciling used in the program.

Are there any other likely causes of this kind of z-fighting?

[image: z-fighting]
[image: Not overlapping]

The vertex matrix is produced as follows:

```
Matrix4 transform_matrix;
Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float) (45 * Math.PI / 180), aspect_ratio, 1, 100, out transform_matrix);
transform_matrix = Matrix4.Mult(transform_matrix, CameraMatrix);
```

and CameraMatrix is the result of this method:

```
public void TransformMatrix(out Matrix4 m)
{
    var t = Matrix4.Identity;
    t.Column3 = new Vector4(Offset);

    var rx = Matrix4.Identity;
    var sine_x = (float) Math.Sin(-RotationX * Math.PI / 180);
    var cos_x = (float) Math.Cos(-RotationX * Math.PI / 180);
    rx.Row1 = new Vector4(0, cos_x, -sine_x, 0);
    rx.Row2 = new Vector4(0, sine_x, cos_x, 0);

    var ry = Matrix4.Identity;
    var sine_y = (float) Math.Sin(-RotationY * Math.PI / 180);
    var cos_y = (float) Math.Cos(-RotationY * Math.PI / 180);
    ry.Row0 = new Vector4(cos_y, 0, sine_y, 0);
    ry.Row2 = new Vector4(-sine_y, 0, cos_y, 0);

    var n = Matrix4.Mult(rx, t);
    n = Matrix4.Mult(ry, n);

    m = n;
}
```

### Update

This is only happening on an NVIDIA card.  Tested with an Intel and the problem did not present.

Comment: Doesn't look like z-fighting to me. Try debugging your projection matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This does not really look like z-fighting. It is a wild guess, but is your program actually using hardware acceleration? Microsoft's software renderer is known to produce corruption like this.

Suggestions:

1. Check that `GL.GetString(StringName.Renderer)` is *not* "Microsoft GDI Renderer", as that would indicate software acceleration.
2. Try requesting a 24bit depth buffer, not a 32bit one, as the latter is not supported by GPUs.
3. Double-check your depth buffer bits via `Context.GraphicsMode.Depth`. The default is 16bits.

What happens when you request 32bits depends on the version of OpenTK you are using. OpenTK 1.0 would fall back to software acceleration for unsupported modes (like 32bit depth buffers). OpenTK 1.1 will try harder to give you a matching `GraphicsMode` and will only fall back to software acceleration as a last resort.

Comment: 32-bit depth buffers ***are*** supported by GPUs. Many ICDs on Windows do not expose a pixel format for the default framebuffer that has a 32-bit depth buffer, however. In other words, you often have to use an FBO to get access to a 32-bit depth format.

Comment: Definitely not that first one since I am testing this on Linux.  Renderer is `GeForce GTX 560/PCIe/SSE2`.  Depth is 24-bit by default.

Comment: This looks really weird. Can you upload a test project somewhere?